# How to load lots of files into one RDD in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I use `saveAsTextFile` method to save `RDD`, but it is not in a file, instead there are many parts files as the following picture.

[image]

So, my question is how to reload these files into one RDD.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly _"reload"_ is in _"how to reload these files into one RDD"_? Do you want to load the files back into an RDD after they're saved using `saveAsTextFile`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Spark locally, rather than in a distributed manner is my guess. When you use saveAsTextFile it is just saving these using Hadoop's file writer and creating a file per RDD partition. One thing you could do is `coalesce` the partition to 1 file before writing if you want a single file. But if you go up one folder you will find that the folder's name is that which you saved. So you can just `sc.textFile` using that same path and it will pull everything into the partitions once again.

Answer (score 0):

you know what? I just found it very elegant:
say your files are all in the /output directory, just use the following command to merge them into one, and then you can easily reload as one RDD:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /output /local/file/path
```

Not a big deal, I'm Leifeng.